# Compiling LZMA SDK in C creates a lib and I want a dll, how can I do this?

Tags: c, dll, sdk, compilation, lzma

I downloaded the `7z SDK`.
I would like to compile the `Ansi C LZMA` `lib` in order to have the `DLL`.
I opened the project in `VS2012`.

In the projects properties, the `scope` is to `DLL`, nevertheless, when i build the project, it creates `lib` and obj files but no `DLL`.

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot,

best regards,

Nixeus

Answer (score 3):

I started off with the advice of Jacob, located the .dsw file, and converted it to Visual Studio Community 2015 RC. I had the same issue as you however, that no dll was created. But there were warnings. Here's what I did.

- Under properties > configuration properties > general, I set both "Output directory" and "Intermediate directory" to $(ProjectDir)Release\
- In the same place I changed "Target Name" to "lzma"
- Under properties > configuration properties > Linker > General, I set "Output file" to "$(ProjectDir)Release\lzma.dll"

And that did it for me.

Comment: As you may have noticed, the "configuration properties > Linker > General > Output file" contains C:\Util\lzma.dll. The generated dll file is there. Weird settings. Just change it to <inherit from parent or project default> would return to normal (C\Util\LzmaLib\x64\Release\LzmaLib.dll. Also the build output message will tell you where the dll is).

Comment: I just found the dll at the same location (C:\Util\LZMA.dll). However, in Visual Studio 2019, the build output message says the wrong location: `1>LzmaLib.vcxproj -> C:\Users\mark\Downloads\C\Util\LzmaLib\.\LzmaLib.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

In the `LZMA SDK` archive you can download from the [7-Zip website](http://7-zip.org/) there is a `Visual Studio` project in folder `C\Util\LzmaLib` named `LzmaLib.dsw` which generates a `sln` after you open it with `Visual Studio`(works with `VS2008`, I didn't try with `VS2012` but it should work).

Compiling this project will generate the wanted `LZMA.dll` in `C:\Util` folder.

Let me know if it worked.